# Magento Magic Zoom Plus

Tags: product-images, zoom

I have a **magic zoom plus** on my site on product detail page, I need to **decrease the size of lens** irrespective of image size.

I know lens become bigger and smaller based on zoomed image size but is there any way **I can control this**?

Answer (score 0):

The Magic Zoom Plus hover area is calculated automatically based upon:

1. Small image dimensions (px)
2. Zoom image dimensions
3. Size of zoom window (px or %)

You can adjust those settings on the Magic Zoom Plus settings page inside your Magento admin.

In general, the larger your original image, the larger the zoom.

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/integration/) for examples.

To change the dimensions of the zoom box, apply the options **zoomWidth** and/or **zoomHeight**. For example:

```
<a href="large.jpg" class="MagicZoom" data-options="zoomWidth:400px; zoomHeight:400px"><img src="small.jpg"></a>
```

Comment: Is there any way i can change the ratio of lens in the code?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Please share a link to your page and screenshots. If you're using a magnifying glass, it is not possible to set a size but it is possible to allow the user to change the lens size by spinning the mousewheel. If you're using the zoom window, you can set the zoomHeight and zoomWidth to control the dimensions. A code example has been added to the answer above.